# Return IP addresses from a list in quotes - Ansible

Tags: ansible

Hoping someone can assist.  I'm trying to extract IP addresses from a list so that they may be used in a URI call in Ansible, so the basic code I have is

```
    Vars: 
     servers:
      - name: Backups 
        ipaddr: 
          - "192.168.10.10"
          - "192.168.20.10"
          - "192.168.30.10"
```

Then I run this code

```
    - name: list vars      
    debug: 
    msg: "{{ item.ipaddr | flatten | join (',')}}"
    loop: "{{servers}}"
```

But the output is

```
    "msg": "192.168.40.10,192.168.50.10,192.168.60.10"
```

Whereas I need this returned with the quotes

```
    "msg": "192.168.40.10","192.168.50.10","192.168.60.10"
```

Sure I am missing something obvious but any help would be gratefully received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jinja_dude but managed to fix this with

```
    {{ item.ipaddr | to_json | join() }}
```

Which produced the result

```
    "msg": [
    "192.168.40.10",
    "192.168.50.10",
    "192.168.60.10"
]
```

And this was accepted in my URI call

Comment: Hey, @steve glad to know that! if my answer was useful for you I would be happy if you upvote it

Comment: Done!, but it mentions as a newbie it doesn't register but hopefully it will on your stats.  Thank you again for taking the time to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Hello steve I think a way of achieving something similar is using this :

```yaml
 "{{ item.ipaddr | map('quote') | flatten | join(', ') }}"
```

Otherwise there is also this already implemented filter in ansible that will help you have each ip between quotes :

```yaml
"{{ item.ipaddr | map("regex_replace","(.+)","\'\\1\'") | flatten | join(',')}}"
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time too respond, unfortunately didn't have any luck with either of those.  The first only returned what I already had

"msg": "192.168.40.10, 192.168.50.10, 192.168.60.10"

And the second game an error ERROR! 

We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: No JSON object could be decoded

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key

Comment: Have you tried :
 "{{ item.ipaddr | map('quote') | join(', ') }}"

Comment: Thanks again for trying to help me with this, tried a number of different things and that strings is again close but doesn't get the quotes around the IP's individually.

 "msg": "192.168.10.10, 192.168.20.10, 192.168.30.10"

I have had better luck with "[{{ item.ipaddr | flatten | to_yaml }}]" which does seem to give me almost what I need but with some extra characters (which I think are just a 'feature' of debug)

"msg": "[\"192.168.40.10\", \"192.168.50.10\", \"192.168.60.10\"]"

However when I put that as part of my body in the URI call it tells me it's not a valid string